# HttpWebRequest only send Get requests and not post

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

im trying to send POST request using HttpWebRequest and fiddler shows me that im sending GET?
any help will be appreciated since im able to see what im doing wrong.

code :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(LOGIN_API_BASE_URL);
        string postString = string.Format("api_email={0}&api_password={1}", EMAIL, PASSWORD);
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postString);
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = cookies;
        //request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;
        request.Timeout = i_timeout;
        //request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208 Firefox/3.0.1";
        //request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        //request.Referer = "https://accounts.craigslist.org";

        using (Stream writer  = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            writer.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            //writer.Close();
        }

        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();

        responseReader.Close();
        request.GetResponse().Close();
```

Comment: You are sending a password as plain text?

Comment: @Arran im working according to API instructions and tried to send it as plain text and as bytes but that is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

ok found the problem, the url im sending the request to is http://domain.com and when i send it to http://www.domain.com it works and send a post. so new question why is that? ( the answer will get the answer to my question as i dont like the idea of voting my self )

Comment: Sounds like there may be URL rewriting on the server that redirects to the canonical form of www.domain.com. Poorly planned URL rewriting often forgets to take into account POST requests, and thus, the redirect transforms it to a GET request.

Comment: @Chris ok ill bite. but when i try to use http://www.requestmaker.com/ to test it the request is sent ok and response is ok also returning with http 302 ( thats fine cause im expecting only the cookie in the response ) but in my code even with post still im getting 404 error.... again thanks for the help

Comment: Depending on the site in question, this could still be the case. If using ASP.NET MVC for example, and the action defined at domain.com/home/dostuff is POST only, attempting to make a GET request will result in a 404 error, since there is no endpoint that accepts GET requests.

Comment: not mvc, its a java server, and im sending the same params throw both my app and the request maker, in request maker it works and in my app not ( both are now POST ) for testing purposes here is the url: 
http://clicksmob.com/analytics-new-api/login_api

Comment: Without knowing the details of the request and response, it's hard to say. Can you post censored request/response headers in your question?

Comment: here is the site im calling :
http://clicksmob.com/analytics-new-api/login_api 
and test user name is: liran1802@walla.co.il password : 123456

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40202/discussion-between-liran-and-chris)